# cordova.file.* - all locations are null in iOS. Works in Android

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using the cordova-file-plugin, but it shows all location in iOS as null. This works perfectly with android. Am I missing some permissions for iOS or something?

Comment: read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite @JesseMonroy650's advice to check the docs (which, to my experience, tends to be a buggy, incomplete documentation), this issue is not clearly explained in the docs. It also happened to me, and I solved it in a more drastic way:

1. Remove the `org.apache.cordova.file` plugin, and, sadly, all of its dependent plugins (like `org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`, `org.apache.cordova.media`, `org.chromium.zip` and any other), using `cordova plugin rm [plugin-name]`. To know the plugin names, run `cordova plugins`.
2. Install the newer version of the file plugin. The new cordova plugins have a different name. To get the new name, replace `org.apache.cordova.` with `cordova-plugin-`. In this case, use `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`to install the file plugin
3. Reinstall any other plugin you had to remove. You can use the new versions (`cordova-plugin-`) or the old ones (`org.apache.cordova.`). I used the new version of the `file-transfer`.
4. Add in your `config.xml` this line: `<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />` or `<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />`, [based on your needs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#ios-persistent-storage-location).
5. Make sure you run `cordova prepare` after you complete these steps.
6. Open Xcode, clean the project with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, and then build it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Finally, run the project with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. *You could also clean the project and use the play button, but in these kind of cases cases, I like to do the steps manually. Yeah, I'm a little weird.*

Comment: Yep - It was the new plugin mismatch. I went even more drastic and cleaned up the entire plugin directory and reinstalled the plugins. This was quite weird because I got caught in between a lot of upgrade cycles - cordova, ionic framework, and the plugin changes to new repo. it was hell trying to fix all of it. Simpler to start fresh

Answer (score 0):

It also happens when your file name contains white space (on ios). I wasted my whole day by updating plugins and cordova and ionic. I resolved by removing white space from file name on ios and its done. I am using fileopener2 plugin for open the local file by url.

Comment: Which filename?